# Generator and functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

I'm not sure what's happening here.  Today is my first foray into the world of generators.  I put this into the pythontutor visualizer but I'm not understanding why this is happening.  The visualizer spits out "generator return instance".  I've read the other SO threads that are similar to mine though I'm unfortunately not understanding why this is.  In addition to this specific issue I'd greatly appreciate any thoughts on great ways to learn to use generators correctly and efficiently.  Thank you!

```
def even(nums):
    for number in nums:
        if number % 2 == 0:
             yield number


def find_evens(number_list):
    return even(number_list)

>>> find_evens([1,2,3,4,5,6])
<generator object even at 0x104f7af10>
```

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/196/comprehensions/739/generator-expressions#t=201612122216342369916

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Python REPL is just giving your back the default representation of the generator object.

A generator won't yield it's values on its own, you'll have to force it to. Many options exist to force, for example wrapping it in a `list`:

```
list(find_evens([1,2,3,4,5,6]))
[2, 4, 6]
```

Or, similarly, by iterating through it:

```
for i in find_evens([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]):
    print(i)
```

Both these examples (looping, calling `list`) will call `__next__` on the generator object forcing it to return the next value according to the statements you've written.

As for a bit more information on these, you could always take a look at the [Python wiki Page on Generator.](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators)

Answer (score 2):

A *generator object* has the method `__next__()`.

This method *must be called* (explicitly or *implicitly*) to **obtain its next value**.

(It is called *implicitly* and *repeatedly* until the exhaustion by *using the generator object*  in some contexts - as in `for` loop or `list()` function.)

Once a generator object is created:

- the *1st  use* of the `__next__()` method returns the value of the *1st*  `yield` statement,
- the *2nd use* of the `__next__()` method returns the value of the *2nd* `yield` statement,
- .......
- and so on - until there is *no* additional `yield` statement, in which case the *generator object* is *exhausted* (and `useless`) as it from this moment gives - instead of the next value - only the exception `StopIteration`.

Compare

```
>>> even([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]).__next__()
2
>>> even([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]).__next__()
2
>>> even([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]).__next__()
2
```

with

```
>>> gen = even([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
>>>
>>> gen.__next__()
2
>>> gen.__next__()
4
>>> gen.__next__()
6
>>> gen.__next__()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#13>", line 1, in <module>
    gen.__next__()
StopIteration
>>>
>>> gen.__next__()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#13>", line 1, in <module>
    gen.__next__()
StopIteration
```

In the first case *a generator* is created *again and again*, while in the second one it is created *once* and then used repeatedly *until its exhaustion* (and 1 more time - only for the illustration).

Answer (score 0):

You can imagine that you only get a pointer to where a generator is located. By printing it, you print the location where it is. But to actually get the values, you have to say *give me the values*, and you do that either by doing `list` or using it in a `for` loop.